# How to convert html to delta in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, quill

I architect CRUD Board with Vue, FastAPI.

what I want to do is getting a delta data from HTML str.

the following code, I tried to get it.
but I can't get anything.

After parsing the JSON file, HTML is obtained, and the HTML file is converted to delta so that it can be used in the editor.
After that, I want to insert the converted delta into the editor so that the existing contents appear on the edit page as is so that I can edit it, but nothing appears.

```js
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h5 class="my-3 border-bottom pb-2">게시글 수정</h5>
    <!-- <ErrorComponent :error="error" /> -->
    <form @submit.prevent="updatePost" class="my-3">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="title" class="form-label">제목</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" v-model="title">
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="content" class="form-label">내용</label>
        <QuillEditor
                class="editor"
                ref="myTextEditor"
                :disabled="false"
                :value="content"
                :options="editorOption"
                @blur="onEditorBlur($event)"
                @focus="onEditorFocus($event)"
                @ready="onEditorReady($event)"
                v-model:content="rawDelta"
            />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">수정하기</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import fastapi from '../lib/api'
// import ErrorComponent from "../components/ErrorComponent.vue"

import { QuillEditor } from '@vueup/vue-quill'
import '@vueup/vue-quill/dist/vue-quill.snow.css';

export default {
  components: {
    QuillEditor,
    // ErrorComponent
  },
  props: {
    post_id: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      error: { detail: [] },
      title: '',
      content: '',
      rawHtml: '',
      rawDelta: ''
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    fastapi('get', `/user/post/detail/${this.post_id}`, {}, (json) => {
                this.title = json.title;
                this.content = json.content;
                this.convertDeltaToHtml(JSON.parse(json.content))
                this.converHtmltoDelta(this.rawHtml)
            });
  },
  methods: {

    postNotice() {
        let url = "/user/post/create"
        let params = {
            title: this.title,
            content: JSON.stringify(this.content),
            is_notice: false
        }
        fastapi('post', url, params,
        () => {
            this.$router.push("/user/post_list")
        },
        (json_error) => {
            this.error = json_error
        }
        )
        },

    updatePost() {
      let url = '/user/post/update';
      let params = {
        post_id: this.post_id,
        title: this.title,
        content: this.content
      };
      fastapi('put', url, params, () => {
          this.$router.push("/user/post/detail/"+this.post_id)
      },
      (err_json) => {
          this.error = err_json
      })
    },

    convertDeltaToHtml(delta){
          var QuillDeltaToHtmlConverter = require('quill-delta-to-html').QuillDeltaToHtmlConverter;
          var converter = new QuillDeltaToHtmlConverter(delta.ops, {});
          this.rawHtml = converter.convert();
        },

    converHtmltoDelta(html){
      const quillEditor = this.$refs.myTextEditor.quill;
      console.log(quillEditor)
      const delta = quillEditor.clipboard.convert(html);
      this.rawDelta = delta;
    },
      
    onEditorBlur(editor) {
      console.log("editor blur!", editor);
    },
    onEditorFocus(editor) {
        console.log("editor focus!", editor);
    },
    onEditorReady(editor) {
        console.log("editor ready!", editor);
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

```
converHtmltoDelta(html){
      const quillEditor = this.$refs.myTextEditor.quill;
      console.log(quillEditor)
      const delta = quillEditor.clipboard.convert(html);
      this.rawDelta = delta;
    },
```

I analyze this code to get a error.
when I print log above quillEditor, I got an undefined.
Could this be the problem? I don't know how to convert

I looked for a way to convert a json file to delta, and a way to convert an html file to delta, but I couldn't find one and the conversion wasn't easy.

What I want is to display what is saved as JSON inside the editor and then change it so that it can be modified.

Comment: start with just logging the value of `this.$refs.myTextEditor` and see if it exists before trying to access any properties of it.  Either the editor is not yet fully initialized or accessible in the DOM, or you're trying to access a wrong property.  From reviewing the [API](https://vueup.github.io/vue-quill/api/methods.html#getquill) it's probably the latter (wrong property). You likely want to use `.getQuill()` instead of `.quill`